# How do I "Re-Randomize" Particle Emmission?

Tags: particles

So I have two planes that are emitting particles with the default settings.
However, the "randomized" particle emission is *exactly the same* for both planes.

Is there a way that I can "re-randomize" the distribution so that this is not the case?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the "seed" value next to the emitter type selection:

[image]